# In Node.js, what does "var dnode = require('denode') mean when there is no file called 'denode'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code for the question is the following, and I am confused by two lines in particular.

```
var dnodeport = 50001;
var dnode = require('dnode');


//console.log( waitRoom );
console.log( "One Eyed Jack Server 0.003(0601) Started at " + timeStamp );
//console.log( "One Eyed Jack Server 0.001(0414) Started at " + timeStamp );
//console.log( process.argv ); // node ps server_id port
//console.log( process.argv.length );
if ( 3 <= process.argv.length ) {
  port = process.argv[2];
  dnodeport = Number(port) + Number(1);
}

console.log("Dnode init port: " + dnodeport);
var dnodeserver = dnode(function (remote, conn) {
    //this.zing = function (n, cb) { cb(n * 100) };
    this.forceclose = function()
    {
        console.log("force close called");
        for(channelindex in channels)
        {
            for(gameindex in channels[channelindex])
            {
                channels[channelindex][gameindex].SetForceCloseRoom();
            }
        }
    } ............... code after this is cut out for viewability
```

So I have no idea what

```
var dnode = require('dnode');
```

means when there is no file called dnode.js in the directory.

And also, I don't know what

```
var dnodeserver = dnode(function (remote, conn) {
```

means.

Please help my noobness.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dnode = require('dnode');
```

means requiring the **module** 'dnode'

aka `node_modules/dnode/index.js` (either in local scope, or global scope).

If the module cannot be found, then you'll get an error.

To require a file (e.g. dnode.js), you will need to do:

```
var dnode = require('./dnode');
```

Comment: It's stuff installed with npm, see https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm

Answer (score 0):

`var dnode = require('dnode');`

It will not look for a local file(`dnode.js`) in your directory structure but it will look for a file in the `node_modules` folder(`node_modules/dnode/index.js`) in the current directory or in its parent directory.

Please refer [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)